# moving elements with jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I use jQuery to move an element from:

```
position: absolute;
left: 169px;
top: 182px;
```

to:

```
position: absolute;
left: 169px;
top: 230px;
```

with clear moving so not just css, it has to be moving.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pHwMK/

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $("div.ele").animate({ top: '230px' });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

What you mean is animation? Assuming an element with `id="someElement"` already has `position:absolute` and `left:169px`, then:

```
$('#someElement').animate({top: 230});
```

If you need to set the initial CSS on the element before animating it, then have an extra `.css()` call before `.animate()`:

```
$('#someElement').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 169,
    top: 182
}).animate({top: 230});
```