# How do I make a div move on mouse over with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

The html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<title>Empty</title>

<script type="text/JavaScript">

<!--

-->

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="blackbox" id="specialbox"><p class="boxtext">Text</p></div>
<div class="blackbox"><p class="boxtext">Hem</p></div>
<div class="blackbox"><p class="boxtext">Stugan</p></div>
<div class="blackbox"><p class="boxtext">Info</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url('images/bkrnd.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.boxtext {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 45px;
}

#specialbox {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.blackbox {
    height: 75px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #000000;

    opacity: 0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    line-height: 73px;
}

p {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

When I hover the mouse over the `div` called "blackbox" I want it to move a little to the right. It has to be done with javascript. I've tried every bit of code and tutorials I've googled but they won't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try jQuery and .css('margin', '150px');

Comment: Where's your JavaScript? "I've tried every bit of code and tutorials I've googled but they wont work" --> Give us an example in which it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why use javascript? its simpler with css:

```
.blackbox:hover {
   margin-left: 10px;
}
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gshNP/

for animation use:

```
.blackbox:hover {
  margin-left: 10px;    
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  -moz-transition: margin-left .5s; /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: margin-left .5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: margin-left .5s; /* Opera */
}
```

Comment: `i want it to move a little to the right` . How do you know how much is that `little` is when you put it on the right side of the screen :)

Comment: Great. user2..I now understood that you wanted simple moving, and not like an animation. My example was like an animation moving, with every hover :) ok, great that you have found you answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to surround your `blackbox` divs with one div like:

**EDIT:**

```
<div class="blackbox" onmouseover="moveDiv(this);" style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:108px;"id="specialbox"><p class="boxtext">Wedén</p></div>
<div class="blackbox" onmouseover="moveDiv(this);" style="position:absolute; top:150px; left:108px;"<p class="boxtext">Hem</p></div>
<div class="blackbox" onmouseover="moveDiv(this);" style="position:absolute; top:200px; left:108px;"<p class="boxtext">Stugan</p></div>
<div class="blackbox" onmouseover="moveDiv(this);" style="position:absolute; top:250px; left:108px;"<p class="boxtext">Info</p></div>
```

And then use javascript, something like this:

```
function moveDiv(divRef)
{
 var newTop = divRef.style.top;
 newTop = parseInt(newTop);
 newTop += 10;
 divRef.style.top = newTop + 'px';
};
```

Take look at live example here: http://jsbin.com/agejud/2/

This above is just as an example. If you want to apply to your example, you should add propery to your blackbox in your css. Something like this:

```
.boxtext {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 45px;

    left: 0px;
}
```

Or you could use jQuery for more smooth transition. You can find an example here: [moving elements with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998757/moving-elements-with-jquery)

Comment: Alright, this does more than everything i've tried so far. I forgot to mention that i want the blackbox divs to move individually on mouse-over. I tried surrounding only one of the divs with

`<div id="helper" onmouseover="moveDiv(this);" style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:108px;">

<div class="blackbox"><p class="boxtext">Hem</p></div>
</div>`


But that just messed up the positioning of the divs.

I have no idea how to format my comment, i'm sorry.

Comment: @user2195880 I have updated the answer. Please take a look not. And it is ok for not formatting comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a very old question but I'll throw in this option anyway. This is basically a javascript method of moving a Div in a sort of "floating" manner using the translate3d css property.

It's a mix of CSS and javascript in a sort of rudimentary way of adding the transform CSS property to the elements at different points of interaction with the mouse.

It's not great coding but it sort of works. I'm pretty new to coding in general so... bear with my code. I'm sure many have shorter and better ways to achieve this, hopefully this is a good start.

```js
const a = "transition: all 2s ease; transform: translate3d(-4.234px, 5px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;";
const b = "transition: all 2s ease; transform: translate3d(4.234px, -5px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;";
const c = "transition: all 2s ease; transform: translate3d(-4.234px, -5px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;";
const d = "transition: all 2s ease; transform: translate3d(4.234px, 5px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;";
const e = "transition: all 2s ease; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg);transform-style: preserve-3d;";
const f = "transition: all 2s ease; transform: translate3d(14px, -0.03px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg);transform-style: preserve-3d;";
const g = "transition: all 2s ease; transform: translate3d(-14px, -0.03px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg);transform-style: preserve-3d;";
const h = "transition: all 2s ease; transform: translate3d(-14px, 0.03px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg);transform-style: preserve-3d;";
const i = "transition: all 2s ease; transform: translate3d(14px, 0.03px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg);transform-style: preserve-3d;";

const img = document.getElementById("img");
img.style.cssText = d;

const div = document.getElementById("targetbox");
div.style.cssText = f;

const anchor = document.getElementById("anchor");
anchor.style.cssText = e;

anchor.onmouseenter = function() {
  img.style.cssText = b;
  div.style.cssText = g;
}
anchor.onmouseover = function() {
  img.style.cssText = c;
  div.style.cssText = i;
}
anchor.onmousemove = function() {
  img.style.cssText = a;
  div.style.cssText = h;
}
anchor.onmouseout = function() {
  img.style.cssText = c;
  div.style.cssText = f;
}
anchor.onmouseleave = function() {
  img.style.cssText = b;
  div.style.cssText = i;
}
```

```css
.boxtext {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#targetbox {
  margin: 0 0 10px 5px;
}

.blackbox {
  height: 75px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  line-height: 7px;
  left: -20px;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a id="anchor">
  <img id="img" src="https://i0.wp.com/css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/event-handlers.png?fit=1200%2C600&ssl=1" 30vw>
  <div id="targetbox" class="blackbox">
    <h3 class="boxtext"> Hello World </h3>
    <p> Floating div</p>
  </div>
</a>
```